# Get parentNode of Current Script Tag

Tags: javascript, document, frame, title, parent-node

Is there any way to get the parent node of current script tag. I wanted to assign id attribute to the script tag but found that it does not support standard attributes.

Actually I want to get the title of a document inside a frame and document.title is returning the title of the webpage.

Comment: Just for clarification: are we talking `frame` or an `iframe`?

Comment: Yeah, with those possible exceptions, you can't get the element that the script resides in without an id or other method. You can however use the this keyword for inline functions.

Comment: is the document being loaded into the frame on the same domain as the parent page?

Comment: If you're loading content form another domain (or being loaded into a page on another domain), you can't access the other page's DOM, and therefore, don't have access to its <title> tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
document.currentScript.parentNode
```

The documentation for [Document.currentScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) says:

> Returns the  element whose script is currently being
>   processed.